# Creating new image in a loop using OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, for-loop

I am programing some image conversion code with OpenCV and I don't know how can I create image memory buffer to load image on every iteration. I have number of iteration (maxImNumber) and I have an input image. In every loop program must create image that is resized and modified input image. Here is some basic code (concept).

```
    for (int imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < maxImNumber; imageIndex++){
    cvCopy(inputImage, images[imageIndex], 0);
    cvReleaseImage(&inputImage);

    images[imageIndex+1] = cvCreateImage(cvSize((image[imageIndex]->width)/2, image[imageIndex]->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    for (i=1; i < image[imageIndex]->height; i++) {   
        index = 0;      //   
        for(j=0; j < image[imageIndex]->width ; j=j+2){
            // doing some basic matematical operation on image content and store it to new image
            images[imageIndex+1][i][index] = (image[imageIndex][i][j] + image[imageIndex][i][j+2])/2;
            index++
        }
    }

    inputImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize((image[imageIndex+1]->width), image[imageIndex]->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCopy(images[imageIndex+1], inputImage, 0);
}
```

Can somebody, please, explain how can I create this image buffer (images[]) and allocate memory for it. Also how can I access any image in this buffer?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Start using the C++ API of OpenCV!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`images` is just an array of `IplImage` pointers so the following should work:

`IplImage** images = (IplImage**) malloc(sizeof(IplImage*)*maxImNumber)`

Answer (score 1):

or better yet vector images ...
and then images.pushback(newImage) on each loop

Answer (score 0):

Use an `std::vector<IplImage*> images(maxImNumber)`.
Iterate over it once to allocate all images using, e.g. `cvCreateImage()` or `cvCloneimage()`.
When you are done with it iterator over it again and `cvReleaseImage()` all the images.